# Why do browsers have circular logos?

Tags: logos

Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari, Edge...Every web browser seems to have round logos. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Firefox used to be firebird and it's logo was very not-circular

Comment: Netscape navigator's logo was also not circular

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it hasn't got anything to do with user experience.

Comment: I feel like this answer actually does have something to do with UX. Circles are the shapes of togetherness and wholeness. And if that one fact causes a user to use a certain app/browser, won't they go in with a very positive first impression (let's imagine it's the user's first time using the app), isn't that UX. Making the user's experience of a certain piece of software as enjoyable as possible. And if this is achieved through shapes, then doesn't it make this question on topic. 'Cause people could learn that and find some interesting ways of using shapes to make the UX more enjoyable

Answer (score 4):

I believe, when the Internet had launched, they started with a vision of Connecting World together (World=the Icon of Earth). 
Now everyone adopted it, this might be one reason for circular logos.

Answer (score 0):

Also in addition to what @abhisheksharma said, circles are the shapes of community.
An extract from this amazing [infographic](https://blog.hubspot.com/agency/psychology-logo-shapes-infographic):

> Circles: community, friendship, love, relationships, unity, perfection, attention, protection